# Can we isolate the effect of two different control variables in a semi-partial correlation?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, partial-correlation, controlling-for-a-variable

I know that we are able to use a **partial correlation** when we want to correlate X and Y but Z affects *both* of them and that we may use a **semi-partial** correlation when we want to correlate X and Y and we know that Z only affects X.

- In my case, I have two different "Zs"/third variables.The idea is the following: I want to correlate X1 and X2, but I know that Z1 is extremely correlated to X1 and that Z2 is extremely correlated to X2.

So, I'm *not* assuming that Z1 and Z2 are correlated to both X1 and X2 (as it would be via a partial correlation, right?)
I'm *not* assuming that Z1 and Z2 only effects X1 or X2 (as it would be for a semi-partial)

- To put it simpler:

  Z1 is correlated to X1 
  Z2 is correlated to X2 
  I want to see if X1 and X2 are correlated **controlling for the effects of Z1 on X1 and of Z2 on X2**

Obs: all variables are continuos

- **Edit1:** reproducible data: [HERE](https://github.com/Larissa-Cury/ReproducibleDataSet2309.git)

Any ideas would be MUCH appreaciated! Thanks in advance!

- **Edit2:**

I was thinking about this solution after watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xii1jVLnX60&lc=Ugyr1Vlg5pBXqulNTa94AaABAg) and from the kind comment below, I'm really hoping that this may be a good path :

If I apply the same logic as the video's for the partial corr, I guess that maybe it would be all right?

```
res1 <- rstandard(lm(X1 ~ Z1))
res 2 <- rstandard(lm(X2 ~ Z2))
```

so,

```
res1 = > the portion of X1 that is not explained by Z1
res2 = > the portion of X2 that is not explained by Z2
```

so,

```
cor(res1,res2) = > should be the correlation between X1 (accouting for Z1's effect on it) and X2 (accounting for Z2's effect on it), right?
```

- **Question 1**: I'm assuming this would be fine for a Pearson's correlation, but my data is non-parametric. Would it be okay to apply a Spearman's correlation cor(res1, res2) ?
- **Question 2** : why `rstandard` ? Should we always apply this, even if data is non-parametric? (I guess so, since even Spearman corr is going to use Pearson's equation, after ranking the data, right?) but, still, I didn't quite understand why standartizing is a "must"
- **Edit 3** : Using `rstandard` or not

So,

- When I  **standartize** the residuals, I get a value of `Pearson's rho cor(res1, res2)` (0.95) and `slope lm(res1 ~ res2)` (0.95), which differs from `Pearson's rho pcor.test(X1, X2, Z)` (0.96) (I know the difference in this case seems minimal, but I'd want to understand why is there a difference in the first place...)
- when I **don't** standartize, the `Pearson's rho(res1, res2)` (0.96)  is equal to `Pearson's rho pcor.test(X1, X2, Z)` (0.96) , but not to the `slope lm(res1 ~ res2)` (1.477e-04) anymore...why is that?

Comment: idea: take the residuals of x1 in a linear regression on z1, and similarly the residuals of x2 in a regression analysis against z2. find the correlation between the residuals of each variable. If this is not the answer you're looking for, please explain what you need in more detail.

Comment: @KishKash hi, thank you, I was wondering about the same solution! I'm so happy that that seems to be a good path, but  I have some questions. I thought about this after watching this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xii1jVLnX60&lc=Ugyr1Vlg5pBXqulNTa94AaABAg), I've changed a few comments with the author.  I'm gonna add an edit to the post, would you please check it out?

Comment: In regard to the "nonparametric" issue https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/40995/3277

Comment: @ttnphns , hi, thank you for the link, so, would that be okay to check the res1, res2 normality and calculate the Spearman corr between them, then?

Comment: @LarissaCury If I understand the workings of `rstandard` correctly, then I believe it would be fairly safe to drop it. Since it's based on a leave-one-out tactic, for a sufficiently large number of points and extreme outliers notwithstanding, its impact on the result is negligible anyway. I'm not a statistician, though.

Comment: @KishKash , hi, thank you, so the results are quite different when I use ```rstandard``` and when I don't use it, I'll right a follow-up edit giving the details in a moment!

Comment: re Edit 3, 2nd bullet: In principle, shifting and scaling should not have any impact on the correlation of two series of numbers; however, `rstandard` does not apply perfect shifting/scaling of the input series, due to it being implemented with a leave-one-out mechanism. So small differences of 0.01 are to be expected. 
When you apply a linear model of `res1` vs `res2`, the slope is not expected to equal the pearson correlation coefficient; therefore the fact that you got a different number should not be surprising.

Comment: @KishKash , thank you once more! But why is that the slope ```lm(res1 ~ res2)```  is equal to Pearson's (res1, res2) R when I use ```rstand``` and it differs when I don't use it? (I'm sorry if it's a silly question...)

Comment: Not terribly important for the theory underlying the question, but the example dataset has missing pairs of observations. The pattern of missingness is not aligned, so the residuals are misaligned also. You can see this with `table(names(res1) == names(res2))`. Also, I have trouble reproducing the high correlation estimates reported.

Comment: @dipetkov , hi! Thank you. I updated the data file, see if it works now. I've just ran correlations between X1/Z1 and X2/Z2 and they're .98 and .95

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something but (x1, z1) and (x2, z2) are each strongly linearly correlated. After I regress the x's on the z's, the residuals are very noisy and the correlation between res1 and res2 is very low. Can you double check? I think the approach is reasonable but it's also confusing whether you are looking at the correlations between the original variables or between the residuals. (The question seems to be about the latter.)

Comment: So, I'm looking, ultimately, to the relantionship between X1 and X2. That's the most important thing. However, since I know that z1 and z2 have, respectively, a very strong relantionship with X1 and X2, I would like to be able to say that I'm indeed looking at the relantionship between X1 and X2 accounting for their relantions with z1 and z2, 'controling' for z1 and z2 respetively @dipetkov

Comment: z is the same assessment, but done in two languages (aka, 1 and 2) and we know that it has a very strong relantionship with the x scores, that's why we're trying to control for it. However, z1 - x1 and z2 - x2. That's why I cannot use just a partial or semi partial correlation, because the relantion is in respect to the language. Ultimately, we want to know if x1 and x2 increase together or not

Comment: I admit I don't understand what this question is saying. To be honest, you might get a better answer if you simplify. In particular the bit about whether to use `residuals()` or `rstandard()` is, I think, orthogonal to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem

You say

> I'm looking, ultimately [for] the relationship between $X_1$ and $X_2$

But since $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are only related to one of both, you want to address this separately. Let's clarify first what concepts are we dealing with.

#### Definitions

Let us first recall the definition of correlation $\rho_{X_1,X_2}$:

$$
\rho_{X_1, X_2} = \frac{\mathbb{E}\bigg[(X_1 - \mathbb{E}[X_1])(X_2 - \mathbb{E}[X_2])\bigg]}{\sigma_{X_1}\sigma_{X_2}}
$$

, where $\sigma_\cdot$ is the standard deviation of a specific variable.

Then, the semi-partial correlation you're interested in by removing the effects of $Z_1$ on $X_1$ and of $Z_2$ on $X_2$ is, that is $\rho_{X_1 | Z_1, X_2 | Z_2}$ is defined as:

$$
\rho_{X_1| Z_1, X_2 |Z_2} = \frac{\mathbb{E}\bigg[(\epsilon_{X_1 \sim Z_1})(\epsilon_{X_2 \sim Z_2})\bigg]}{\sigma_{\epsilon_{X_1 \sim Z_1}}\sigma_{\epsilon_{X_2 \sim Z_2}}} 
$$

, where $\epsilon_\cdot$ correspond to the errors from a model that regresses the variables in the subscript (e.g. the regression of $X_1$ by $Z_1$ if $\epsilon_{X_1 \sim Z_1}$). The differences from the mean disappear since errors are assumed to have mean zero: $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon_\cdot] = 0$

Lastly, let us recall that the slope of a simple linear regression of $Y$ on $X$ is:

$$
\beta_{Y \sim X} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}[X, Y]}{\operatorname{Var}[X]} = \frac{\mathbb{E}\bigg[(X - \mathbb{E}[X])(Y - \mathbb{E}[Y]\bigg]}{\sigma_X \sigma_X} 
$$

We can see that the slope coefficient for the regression of the errors of $X_1$ on the errors of $X_2$, that is $\beta_{\epsilon_{X_1 \sim Z_1} \sim \epsilon_{X_2 \sim Z_2}}$, will be equal to our semi-partial correlation of interest only if $\sigma_X\sigma_X = \sigma_{\epsilon_{X_1 \sim Z_1}}\sigma_{\epsilon_{X_2 \sim Z_2}}$. With this, we can now answer your questions.

#### Answers

**Answer 1**

You say that your "data is non-parametric", which, although often described like this by applied researchers, does not make sense. [A *model* can be parametric or non-parametric, data by itself has no parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/506860/180158). Even more so, there is also the related common misconception [that *data* must be normally distributed, rather than the *errors* from a model.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/342759/180158) What you mean by "okay" depends on what is your goal, and in this case whether the association as measured by ranks (which is what Spearman's correlation does) matters to you.

**Answer 2**

You don't necessarily need to standardize the residuals, as we see from the correlation definition that a correlation **is** a standardized covariance. Thus, computing a correlation will divide by the standard deviations anyways.

**Follow-up answers**

You then ask for why you get different answers from `pcor.test(X1, X2, Z)` than from the previous methods$^1$. Since you do not share your code, I will assume that $Z$ is a vector of both $Z_1$ and $Z_2$. Then, unless $Z_1$ is uncorrelated with $X_2$ and $Z_2$ is uncorrelated with $X_1$ (in which case doing a partial correlation on $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ would have been simpler), it is natural to expect the result to be different: $\rho_{X_1 | Z_1, X_2 | Z_2} \neq \rho_{X_1 | \{Z_1, Z_2\}, X_2 | \{Z_1, Z_2 \}}$.

Then, you ask why the correlation result is different if you do not standardize. Note our last equation in the definition section, the slope coefficient is the covariance divided by the standard deviation of your predictor squared (i.e. the variance). If you want the slope coefficient to equal the correlation, you need it to be divided by the product of standard deviations of both variables. This is exactly what happens when you standardize, since then the standard deviation (and variances) of the variables become one: $\sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_1 | Z_1}} = \sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_2 | Z_2}} = \sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_1 | Z_1}} \times \sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_1 | Z_1}} = \sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_2 | Z_2}} \times \sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_2 | Z_2}} =
\sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_1 | Z_1}} \times \sigma_{\epsilon^{\text{std}}_{X_2 | Z_2}} = 1$.

---

$^1$ This minimal difference could also just be approximation error from how different functions compute the same quantity.